# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'.Program giving error while converting unicode to int

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, unicode

So here is my program snippet which is giving me error..

```
bob_phones={}
for lea in leadArray:

    lead_id=(lea.lead_id).text
    phone = (lea.phone_number).text
    if phone not in bob_phones.keys():
        new={phone:[lead_id]}
        bob_phones.update(new)


for i in getPhonenumber(date):

    if i not in bob_phones.keys():
        status="Not in boberdoo"
        lead_id="Not found"
        #c.writerow([date,i,status,lead_id])
        print str(date) + "  | | " + i + " | | " + status + "  | | " + lead_id
    elif i in bob_phones.keys():
        status = "Found in boberdoo"
        lead_id=int(bob_phones[i])
        #c.writerow([date,i,status,lead_id])
        print str(date) + "  | | " + i + " | | " + status + "  | | " + str(lead_id)



#print missing_leads
return missing_leads
```

so in the else if statement i want to update mysql table with lead_id it fetches but its not letting me to convert it into int from unicode as i am fetching that value from a dictionary.Its giving me this error.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'.Program giving error while converting unicode to int.
```

Can anybody suggest me the alternate way.

Thanks

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: Sorry for that George, i just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

```
if phone not in bob_phones.keys():
    new={phone:[lead_id]}
    bob_phones.update(new)
```

When you're creating the `dict` you are assigning the value as a list (`new={phone:[lead_id]}`) due to the brackets. So remove those square brackets and it should work.

Also, note you don't need an elif statement after your if. Either i is in bob_phones.keys() (the `if` branch) or it's not, so you should just use `else`. This doesn't really change anything, just a point about the logic.

Comment: Oh thanks for your reply JR , I was planning to do something else with the code too, thats why i added elif although thanks for letting me know.